# How can I add different colors to bar in Column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, column-chart

How can i add different colors to Bars in Column chart. Adding colors field in option is not working. Please help.

Below is the code snippet:

```
tdata.addRow([col1, arr[0].Manual])
        tdata.addRow([col2, arr[0].Auto]);
        tdata.addRow([col3, arr[0].Amount]);

        options = {
            fontSize: 12,
            height: 430,
            width: 380,
            chartArea: { left: "25%", top: "20%", right: "5%", bottom: "10%" },
            backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
            title: 'Project',
            pieSliceText: 'value',
            colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
            'is3D': true
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('drilldown_div'));
        chart.draw(tdata, options);
        return false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `colors` option applies colors to each series
so if you have 3 colors
you would need 3 y-axis columns

as follows...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'],
    ['A', 100, 120, 130]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

to color individual columns within a series,
use a `'style'` column role

as follows...

note: using a `'style'` column role will invalidate the legend

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],
    ['A', 100, 'red'],
    ['B', 120, 'green'],
    ['C', 130, 'blue']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    legend: 'none'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried colors field but it's not working for me. I used colors : red, blue , green as mentioned above in the code but all the bars became red.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer according to google document, use color property instead of background color.

```
var options = {   width: 400,   height: 240,   title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',   colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'] };

chart.draw(data, options);
```

[you can find more here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts)